# UISplitViewController swipe gesture interferes with other swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a `UISplitViewController` and one of the detail view controllers contains a view which has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` added to it. When I swipe this view in the detail view controller, the gesture is recognized, but the swipe gesture recognizer of the split view controller interferes with it; the master view controller is displayed and the gesture recognizer from the detail controller is ignored.

Implementing and debugging the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` method from the  `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` shows two `UIPanGestureRecognizer` objects: one from the detail view controller and the one from the split view controller, so I'm certain they are interfering with each other.

When I set `presentsWithGesture = NO` on the split view controller, the gesture recognizer inside the detail view controller does work. But that disables the gesture recognizer on the split view controller, so it's not really a solution to the problem.

I've also tried disabling the gesture recognizer on the split view controller, only when I need the other gesture recognizer to work, but it seems that it is not possible to set `presentsWithGesture` once the split view controller has become visible.

I've also tried to disable the default gesture on the split view controller and adding a custom gesture which I can control, but it didn't work. I tried using the `target` and `action` from the split view controller barbutton on the gesture, but it doesn't work. Calling `toggleMasterVisible:` on the split view controller isn't an option either because it's part of the private api.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Can you call `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` on the SplitViewControllers `UIPanGestureRecognizer` ?

Comment: Or return YES from your delegates `gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:` method when the first parameter is your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to give it precedence?

Comment: Calling `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` on the split view controller's `UIPanGestureRecognizer` did the trick, thanks! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I could, although you've already accepted another answer? Out of interest how did you get hold of the split view controller's `UIPanGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: In the detail view's `viewWillAppear` I use `self.splitViewController.view.gestureRecognizers[0]` to get hold of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you disable the `UISplitViewController` pan gesture when you need the other one to work. This should do it:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in [splitViewController gestureRecognizers]) {
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [recognizer setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

You probably don't want to search for it each time, so I would store a reference to that gesture recognizer when the view loads, then just disable and enable as appropriate:

on viewDidLoad:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer in [splitViewController gestureRecognizers]) {
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [self setSplitViewPanGesture:recognizer];
    }
}
```

later:

```
[self.splitViewPanGesture setEnabled:NO];
```

and later:

```
[self.splitViewPanGesture setEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too, but Mike's suggestion works better. It allows the split view controller gesture to keep working, except when I swipe the other view, that swipe is recognized instead and the split view controller no longer interferes.

Comment: Just to be clear, you'd get the same result if you re-enable the split view once the touch ends on the detail view. But requireGestureRecognizerToFail is probably a better solution in this case. Agree.

Comment: Ah I understand. I thought you meant to just simply disable it, but you only disable it when the touch begins. That's actually a better idea, because it allows me to disable it for multiple gestures, not just the one specified with `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`. I was able to implement this by disabling the split view controller gesture in the `shouldReceiveTouch` method, and re-enable it in the detail view gesture action method when its state changes to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`.

Comment: Bingo. I didn't detail when to disable and when to re-enable as there are different methods to do it depending on use case.

Comment: Rather than using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`, if you use `gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:` on your delegate then you can apply it to multiple gestures without having to manually disable and re-enable the split view controllers gesture...

Comment: That works too, but it requires me to replace the split view controller gesture's delegate, of which I'm not sure if that is a good idea, because it is already assigned to the `UIPopoverController` which contains the master view controller.

Comment: In my experience, you can disable then enable the gestureRecognizer immediately afterwards from within the touchesBegan event, and this will stop the gesture from working. Much simpler than having to re-enable later in your code.